# Sveltekit API setup - My endpoint works but my data wont display from Strapi

Tags: api, svelte, strapi, sveltekit

So I have a strapi cms working with a few test items for a blog. I have then set up my sveltekit app and I have an endpoint running on a route '/news/posts' where I placed a +server.ts file and here is the code:

```js
    export const GET = async ({ request }) => {



   const res = await fetch('https://cms.nafuna.tv/api/blogs')
   const info = await res.json()


    return new Response(JSON.stringify(info), { status: 200})
}
```

when I test this with post man I get data:
[image]

so then I created the main files +page.svelte and +page.server.ts, all in the root of '/news' and here is a screenshot:
[image]
I don't know what I am missing to get the data to show up on the page. I am fine with HTML and CSS and basic javascript but this one in sveltekit is confusing me!

Help!

EDIT:
So I managed to get the data flowing into the page.svelte file and I can console logout now. What I still cant do is get it to print and display on the page. Here is the current error:
[image]

and here is the +page.server.ts :

```js
export async function load({ fetch }) {
    const res = await fetch('/news/posts')
    const info = await res.json()
    return { props: { blogs: info.data } };
}
```

and here is  the current +page.svelte:

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import type { PageData } from './$types';
    
    export let data: PageData;

    console.log(data);
    
 
</script>

{#each data.props.blogs as post}

<!-- {#each blogs as blog} -->
<h1>{post.Title}</h1>
{/each}
```

Comment: Posting screenshots instead of proper code extracts is not good etiquette on SO. Regarding your problem, you're apparently using `res.data` instead of `info.data`, as your linter has flagged.

Comment: Sorry abou that, I didnt kow. Thank you for responding. I have made the adjustment on the +pag.server.ts file and it looks like there are no errors, the error I have now is in the svelte file.

Comment: right now my page file code is: `{#each data.blogs as post}
<h1>{post.Title}</h1>
{/each}`

Comment: also tried `{#each blogs as blog}
<h1>{blog.Title}</h1>
{/each}`